# Remove duplicates values based on multiple column with a condition in query editor Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I am new to power bi and would require your help to sort out below issue which I am facing.

Basically I am taking three columns into consideration as below:

[image]

***Question:*** I would like to remove duplicate values from above table based on conditon "
Equal value for "Time" ,"ID" and Absolute difference in "Time spent" is lower or equal than 1"
as you can see in the image Rows highlighted falls in this category.

I would like to get these below rows removed based upon condition.

[image]

Question: I would like to remove duplicate values from above table based on conditon "
Equal value for "Time" ,"ID" and Absolute difference in "Time spent" is lower or equal than 1"
as you can see in the image Rows highlighted falls in this category.

I would like to get these below rows removed based upon condition.

[image]

I am able to perform this in excel by making us of a fourth column with formulae `=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3=B2,ABS(F3-F2)<1),"problem",0)` and then filtering out the rows marked as probelm.  Please help!!

Regards

Mahi

Comment: What about rows 7 and 9? Those are duplicates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the suggestion from @Alexis Olson works just fine, but since you specifically mentioned the `Query Editor`, here's how I would do it there:

---

1. Have your data loaded like below, and just accept the changes made under `Changed Type`:

[image]

Don't worry about the other steps under the `Query Settings`. We'll get to that eventually.

2. Select `Add Column` and click `Index Column`, so that you get this:

[image]

3. Select `Add Column`, click `Custom Column` and insert this little formula in the appearing dialog box `Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each #"Added Index"[Time Spent]{[Index]}-#"Added Index"[Time Spent]{[Index]-1})`:

[image]

4. Click `OK`, and make sure that you're getting this:

[image]

5. I think this step is a little weird, but you'll have to click 'Table' there in the column:

[image]

6. You will get an Error message in the first row, but you can remove that by right-clicking that column, and clicking `Remove Errors`:

[image]

7. Now you can click the drop-down menu in the Custom Column, select Number Filter and  `Does Not Equal`

[image]

8. And insert 0, or select 0 from the drop-down menu in the dialog box:

[image]

9. This is it, your required numbers should now be filtered away:

[image]

Note, however, that this procedure comes at a cost since you're losing the first value due to the first step in the indexing. If the rest of this is something you can use, I can see if we can fix that last little part as well.

Comment: Hi vestland thanks for your help this worked well :)

Comment: No problem! We need more activity on Power BI related problems on this forum =) Now that you've earned more than 15 reputation points, you've got the possibility to upvote answers that are useful to you. And that does not have to be limited to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick a representative `[Time Spent]` value from each unique set of rows by taking a max or min over the list of "duplicate" values. Here's the formula for such a custom column, which I'll call `[Min Time]`:

```
= List.Min(
      Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step",
          (C) => (C[Time] = [Time] and
                  C[ID] = [ID] and
                  Number.Abs(C[Time Spent] - [Time Spent]) < 1)
      )[Time Spent])
```

Once you have this custom column, you can group by `[Time]`, `[ID]`, and `[Min Time]` to roll up the duplicates and then rename the `[Min Time]` column to `[Time Spent]`.